# counting number of pairs of elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

(a) List all subgroups of the quaternion group $Q_8 = \{±1,±i,±j,±k\}$ and arrange them in a picture indicating inclusion among the subgroups.

(Recall the relations $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = −1$ and $ij = k$, $ji = −k$, $jk = i$, $kj = −i$, $ki = j$, $ik = −j$)

(b) Count the number of pairs of elements $a,b ∈ Q_8$ such that $<a,b> = Q_8$.

For (a), I got (correct if I am wrong)

$\{1\}$, $\{1,-1\}$, $\{1,-1,\pm\ i\}$, $\{1,-1,\pm\ j\}$, $\{1,-1,\pm\ k\}$, $Q_8$

For part b, I don't know what to do. Please tell me what to do.

Can someone also give me a simple definition of $<a,b>$ as well please.

This is what I think it is:

$1 \cdot 1$

$1 \cdot -1$

$1 \cdot$ $i$, $j$ or $k$

$-1 \cdot$ $i$, $j$ or $k$

$1 \cdot$ $-i$, $-j$ or $-k$

$-1 \cdot$ $-i$, $-j$ or $-k$

that is $14$ so far.

The recall info, gives $9$ more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Definition : Let $G$ be a group and $S$ a non empty subset of 
>   $G$. The group $\langle S\rangle$ is defined to be the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $S$ (this is always defined because being a subgroup of $G$ containing $S$ is stable by intersection).

Usually (especially when $S$ is finite) we need the following expression of $\langle S\rangle$ :

> Proposition: Let $G$ be a group and $S$ a non empty subset of 
>   $G$.
>
> $$\langle S\rangle=\{1_G\}\cup\{s_1^{\epsilon_1}...s_r^{\epsilon_r}\mid r>0\text{, } (s_1,...,s_r)\in S^r\text{ and }(\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_r)\in \{\pm1\}^r\}$$
>
> That is $\langle S\rangle$ is exactly the subgroup of $G$ consisting of elements that can be written as a product of elements of $S$ and their inverses.

How you should handle the question b) efficiently... Don't begin  by looking at all pairs, just look at the group generated by one element. You have $\langle 1\rangle=1$,  $\langle \pm 1\rangle$ is a group of order $2$ and  $\langle x\rangle$ is a group of order $4$ if $x\in\{\pm i,\pm j\pm k\}$.

Well the group is of order $8$ so that the last $6$ groups are maximal (using Lagrange). It means that if you add any element $y$ to $\langle x\rangle$ such that $y\notin \langle x\rangle$ then the group generated by both $y$ and $x$ will be the whole group.

From this it follows that any pair $(x,y)\in\{\pm i,\pm j\pm k\}^2$ such that $x\neq \pm y$ will generate the group. On the other hand if $x=\pm y
$ then clearly $\langle x\rangle=\langle y\rangle$ so $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle x\rangle$ is not the whole group.

Hence you get $24$ generating pair from the set $\{\pm i,\pm j\pm k\}^2$. Since for each $x\in \{\pm i,\pm j\pm k\}$ you get exactly four generating pairs $(x,y)$ with $y\in  \{\pm i,\pm j\pm k\}$.

The other pairs will never generate the whole group for if $x=1$ then 
$\langle x,y\rangle=\langle y\rangle$.

And if $x=-1$ and $y\neq 1$ then $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle y\rangle$.

Comment: So the only pairs that can generate the whole group are $<i,j>$ and $<i,k>$ and $<j,k>$ right?

Comment: @snowman, they all generate the group but you should also add signs : $\langle i,j\rangle$, $\langle -i,j\rangle$, $\langle i,-j\rangle$ and $\langle -i,-j\rangle$ and same thing for $(i,k)$ and $(j,k)$... On the whole you get $12$ couples. Finally, if a couple $(x,y)$ generates the group then $(y,x)$ also generates the group so that you must add one "reverse" couple for each couple you found. Finally this leads to $24$ couples.